# What would an animal that inhabits the sky be called?

Tags: fauna

Today we know of two base habitats: Terrestrial and Aquatic. Land and Water, respectively. Dogs are terrestrial: living on land and Fish are aquatic: living in the water. So what would an animal that spends its whole life Airbourne be called?

Comment: Doctor who called them sky fish.  https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Sky_fish

Comment: What's wrong with [Aerial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aerial)?

Comment: @kikirex  I guess I forgot about that. Thanks for reminding me. Could you put that into an answer proper so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ### Aerial
- ### Empyrean
- ### Air-based
- ### Skyborne
- ### Floaty-toaty

All of these suggestions are equally valid for a Worldbuilder. You can even make up your own word or expression if you want to.

Comment: If it's a bread-based lifeform you could even call it "floaty-toasty"

Comment: 5 answers in a single post are enough to understand why "what should I name X?" is always too broad and opinion based